# Redis zrangebyscore performance, when min is -inf

Tags: redis, time-complexity

Time complexity of zrangebyscore is O(Log(N))

What if I run zrangebyscore with `min = -inf` and limit 1, is it alow O(log(n))? or O(1)?

Answer (score 1):

`ZRANGEBYSCORE` is **O(Log(N) + M)**, where "N" is the number of elements in the sorted set and "M" is the number of elements being returned.

So your complexity computation needs to account for the logarithm of the number of elements in your set plus one.

[ZRANGEBYSCORE - Redis Documentation](https://redis.io/commands/ZRANGEBYSCORE)